# How to enable an "Always on Display" mode in Nokia 9 for JUST notifications?

Tags: screen, screen-timeout, nokia-9

In Nokia 9 with Android 10, I set `Settings=>Display=>Advance=>Screen timeout` to 30 seconds, but I still like be aware when I have notifications waiting to be reviewed.

In `Settings=>Display=>Advanced` there are `Glance view` options:

[image: The Glance view settings]

The default `Glance display duration` is `30 seconds`. But I like to see all of the notifications which I missed when I wasn't around my phone, so I've changed it to `Always on`...which got the screen to be constantly on!

[image: Glace display duration]

True, it's not "fully" on. It's a black screen with a clock and battery percentage. But is there any way to keep the screen completely off and only keep the glance screen on if I actually have notifications waiting to be reviewed?

In other words, see how Wikipedia describes what I want:

> Typically, an Ambient display solution which turns on the screen only when notifications are present, remains on, but turns off when they are dismissed.
>
> <sup>- [Always on Display, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Always_on_Display)</sup>

Here is what I get when the screen is supposed to be turned off:
[image: Clock and energy bar are shown instead of turning off the screen]

Comment: Based on my experience on Nexus 5 on LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2), Ambient Display only turns on the device for a brief moment when a notification comes, then turns off itself. The display is not permanent on though when there are pending notifications.

Comment: As mentioned, the default is indeed `30 seconds`. But you would think changing it to `Always on` (see new screenshot) should fix it. Alas, it just causes to be on 24/7.